# What else interferes with GPS in background other than Airplane Mode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps

I have a GPS program the runs in the background and I thought I beta tested it thoroughly.
I recently submitted it to the App store for approval.
Since then I have inadvertently found out that Airplane Mode seems to disable the GPS stream and that there is no programatic way to tell if Airplane mode is on or not.
So I have to simply inform the user that, if it is more than 2 seconds since the last GPS fix, they should check that Airplane Mode is off.  This seems a bit kludgy.
Is there a better way to do this?
AND, what else have I forgot about that can stop the GPS stream completely?
Thanks, Carmen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if it is more than 2 seconds since ..

This is a verry bad idea. When standing still at traffic signals, or for other reasons, you don't get a new location.
Either raise to 5 minutes, or better use a status bar which shows GPS is off.
No need to annoy users with messages.

> what else have I forgot about that can stop the GPS stream completely?

- The user disables the Location permission for your app.  (But you can detect that.)

These both reasons, airplane mode and location permission disabled should be the only one from software view. (device internal causes)

Device external causes:
Of course using the device indoors, in tunnels or when having other obstructions to sky this hinders the GPS signal to be received.

Comment: Thanks, I do check that I have permission on program startup and that routine also sends up a message if the user turns off permission while the program is running as it is triggered by a locationmanager didfailwitherrror.  Thanks, Carmen

Comment: I have beta tested hundreds of hours while driving and the 2 seconds seems to work fine.  I am using kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation accuracy and I do get updates every second all the time even when stopped.  I use horizontalAccuracy to determine whether to use the fix or not.  I will leave this up a while longer and if no other GPS interrupter is suggested I will use your answer for reminding me of the permission.  Thanks very much, Carmen

Comment: Thanks, I do not get updates evry second while standing still (Iphone4), I use kCLLocationAccuracyBest, and I too have driven and walked over hundred tracks. That kCLLocationAccuracyBest could be the cause. What happens in Tunnels: Do you get a Location every second with some invalid marker?

Comment: Sorry, I may have mis-spoke, I forgot I change modes to nearest10meters when under 5 mph and don't use GPS data under 5 mph except to determine if I'm going faster than 5 mph again.  I was not getting real reliable data at walking speeds so I changed modes and I am saving some battery now.  Don't have any tunnels around here but I suspect that in the 'best' mode, they use accelerometer and gyros to help out.  Sorry, Carmen

Comment: That should read 'bestfornavigation' mode.  Just to confirm or not, getting fixes when stationary, I just adjusted code to always leave in bestfornavigation mode and updated a label on every didUpdateToLocation.  I stood still on my porch and for two minutes I got a GPS receive every second. Carmen

Comment: And now I made a label flash red for 1/2 second on every didUpdateLocation and it flashes every second while stationary even on 'nearest10meters' mode. I will try this on my husbands iPhone4 and see what happens, are you in one of the significant change modes? Carmen

Comment: No I am at full accuracy. This is really interesting news, because I remeber a post where they said that it ios not possible on ios. I will try it out , and post here an update.

Comment: You will not save battery in nearaest10meters mode, but its is a good idea to ignore location at low speed. nearest 10 uses GPS , and there is no low power GPS mode.

Comment: To topic tunnels: just put your device in a box. do you still get a location every second?